# After setting img.src with v-bind, webpack will not translate the link

Tags: vue-cli

I am using vue-cli-2.9.3 to create a webpack template without change any default settings.

When I try to link to some imgs in my components,such as

```
<template>
  <div>
      <img src="../assets/p1.jpeg">
      <img src="../assets/p2.jpeg">
  </div>
</template>
```

this `img` will be translated to `<img src="/static/img/p1.3b03bfb.jpeg">` and this works fine. But I want to set src with v-bind:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <img :src="`../assets/p${number1}.jpeg`">
      <img :src="`../assets/p${number2}.jpeg`">
  </div>
</template>
```

of course, `number1` equals 1 and `number2` equals 2.

this `img` will be translated to `<img src="../assets/p2.jpeg">`. So,browsers can not find resource in finally project. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

use require to analyze the img url.

```
<img :src=“require(../assets/p${number1}.jpeg)”>
```